# Word for asserting/reaffirming your higher rank in social/professional power structure?

Tags: synonyms

My mind keeps coming back to words such as  *motioning*, *stepping* or *puffing* but I know these aren't the words.

i.e: When someone higher in the power structure asserts their superiority over you

Comment: Do you want a single word or will a phrase do?

Comment: we can try both but it's irking me because i am certain there is one word for what i am trying to say

Comment: posturing! figured it out

Comment: The most common phrase in U.K. civilian as well as military life is ‘pulling rank’.